# Updating realm list removes others

Tags: swift, realm

I am trying to update realm list but for some reason, it deletes last one and adds only new one instead.

This is what I am doing:

```
if !RealmService.shared.ifPortfolioExists(name: newPortfolio.name){//Check if portfolio with given name already exists
            newPortfolio.transactions.append(newTransaction)//Add new transaction to the portfolio's transactions list
            newTransaction.portfolio = newPortfolio//Link portfolio to transaction

            RealmService.shared.create(newPortfolio)
            RealmService.shared.create(newTransaction)

        }else{
            newPortfolio.transactions.append(newTransaction)
            newTransaction.portfolio = newPortfolio
            RealmService.shared.create(newTransaction)

        }
```

And this is the create function:

```
func create<T: Object>(_ object: T){
        do {
            try realm.write{
                realm.add(object, update: true)
            }
        } catch {
            post(error)
        }
    }
```

I also have `primaryKeys()` like mentioned in documentation.

What I am doing wrong, can somebody please explain?

Answer (score 0):

Per the [Realm class description](https://realm.io/docs/swift/latest/api/Classes/Realm.html#/s:FC10RealmSwift5Realm3addFTCS_6Object6updateSb_T_), the object has to have a primary key for the update to work.  Since you didn’t mention that, I assume your realm object lacks it.

> Only pass true to update if the object has a primary key. If no object exists in the Realm with the same primary key value, the object is inserted. Otherwise, the existing object is updated with any changed values.

Comment: I have `primaryKeys()`

Answer (score 0):

Solution was that I had to get all the current ones first.

This is the logic I applied:

```
let currentTransactions = RealmService.shared.realm.objects(Transaction.self).filter("portfolio_name = '\(selectedPortfolioName)'")
        if !RealmService.shared.ifPortfolioExists(name: newPortfolio.name){
            for transaction in currentTransactions{
                newPortfolio.transactions.append(transaction)
            }
            newPortfolio.transactions.append(newTransaction)
            newTransaction.portfolio = newPortfolio

            RealmService.shared.create(newPortfolio)
            RealmService.shared.create(newTransaction)

        }else{
            for transaction in currentTransactions{
                newPortfolio.transactions.append(transaction)
            }
            newPortfolio.transactions.append(newTransaction)
            newTransaction.portfolio = newPortfolio
            RealmService.shared.create(newTransaction)

        }
```